# Matlab r2016a throwing error

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I'm begginer in matlab programming. I'm just find some code on web and I'm trying to compile that code but compile-r throwing me error

Sry for bad english :$

> "Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in jack_immune_projection (line 25)
> Nbre_var=length(w0);"

There is SS of error
http://prntscr.com/bory79

attachment

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5srLRanuS4HUzZsX2hoRTBGMDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You didn't pass any inputs to your function.

Comment: oh, i see that, can u swrite some inputs, and there is one more function in 37 line of code  fit_fun, i have that function in other file fit_fun.m
How I can inject that function with this first jack_immune_projection?

pls help, ty